# Kafka Streams Processor API: Forward the record to a specific stream task based on the key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using the following Processor API topology:

```
Source: STopics (topics: [A, B, C])
  --> P1
Processor: P1 (stores: [P1_Store])
  --> CSink
  <-- STopics
Sink: CSink (topic: Result)
  <-- P1
```

Topics have integer keys, say *ID*. Each topic *A*, *B* and *C* have same number of partitions, say *N*. I have a scenario where records with the same key can appear in any of the source topics. Suppose we have *N* instances created of *P1* processor (or *N* stream tasks) each having a local copy of state store *P1_Store*.

Is there a way to determine the number of instances of *P1* at run-time so that I can send records with the same key to same instance of processor like by using *ID % N* to utilize previous value in the local state store for the *ID* key?

**Update.**  I am re-keying all the records that have empty keys coming at topic A and that new key ID can appear in any topics, here A, B or C.

**Follow-up Question:** If I have two parent processors P00 and P01 of one Processor P1. P00 is running on instance X changes key to 123 and forward, while P01 is running on instance Y and forwards key 123. How to guarantee that key 123 from P00-X and P01-Y always goes to same instance of P1 (say P1-Z so that local state store for 123 is always available at Z)? I don't want P00 and P01 to first write to an intermediate topic and then P1 reads from that intermediate topic. Any alternative to achieve single topology design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input topics are already partitioned by key (what is the default if the ID is set as message key), you don't need to do anything. Kafka Streams will assign the partitions to the task such that the partitioning is preserved.

In particular, if you have N partitions per topic, there will be N tasks, and task 0 will get partitions A-0, B-0, and C-0 assigned and so forth (ie, partitions with the same number from different topics are merged automatically). Also, the number of instances of your processor is the same as the number of tasks. The processor form task X, will process all records from partitions A-X, B-X, and C-X.

If the ID is not the key in your input topics, you would need to repartition the data after setting the ID as key via an additional topic:

```
// using the DSL
stream.selectKey(...)
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(...)

// using Processor API
topology.addSource(...); // read input topics
topology.addProcessor(...); // set ID as key
topology.addSink(...); write to new topic for repartitioning
topology.addSource(...); // read from repartition topic
topology.addProcessor(...); // your processor updating the state
```

Comment: Hi Matthias. Actually, I am re-keying all the records coming at topic A and that new key ID can appear in other topics, here B or C. I need to maintain a state store so that I can retrieve and then update the value associated with ID. 

One solution which seems to be working is that I created an aggregated topic G. If the records are coming at A then re-key else use the original, and write to topic G. This is seems to be working but I want to avoid creation of intermediate topic G.

Comment: Clarification. Re-keying only records with empty key at topic A and that new key can appear again in any topic A, B or C.

Comment: Looks like we can not avoid intermediate topic. I am not using DSL because I need to generate result for each incoming record and forward the updated state to final topic. But with aggregate "not all updates might get sent downstream". That said using transform will work for my case. Thanks.

Comment: If you disable caching (ie, setting `cache.max.bytes.buffering=0`) -- this would make sure that each update is send downstream using the DSL.